# Kernel of a homomorphism from $S_4$ to $\mathbb R^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $S_4$ be the symmetric group on $4$ symbols. Let $f: S_4 \to \Bbb R^*$ be a homomorphism, where $\Bbb R^*$ denotes the non-zero real numbers. Then the number of elements in the set $\{ x\in S_4: f(x) =1\} $ is ....?

Comment: Is $f$ injective? The questions is asking for the cardinality of the kernel of $f$, so do we know more about $f$?

Comment: Kernal of $f$ is normal group so possible orders 1,4,12,24 respecteively the order of normal subgroups trivial group,  klein 4 group,  $A_4$,  $S_4$. Concluding which one

Answer (score 3):

There is only one nonidentity element of finite order in $\mathbb R^*$, namely $-1$. Thus either the homomorphism is trivial or it has image of order $2$. Both are possible. Therefore there are two possible orders of the kernel, which I believe you can figure out.

Comment: The possible kernels are $A_4$ and $S_4$.

Comment: @niz Yes, that's right.